# My Node Express app making these GET requests?

Tags: node.js

I just saw my Express app make a few questionable requests to some Chinese news websites. These same requests, as well as a similar problem has only been brought up in one other question I could find.
The problem came when I added the code. Does anyone know about it?

```
var net = require('net');
net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.on('error', function (err) {
    });
    socket.once('data', function (buf) {
        if (!pref.getSecure()) {
            httpsPort = httpPort;
        }
        var address = buf[0] === 22 ? httpsPort : httpPort;
        var proxy = net.createConnection(address, function () {
            proxy.write(buf);
            socket.pipe(proxy).pipe(socket);
        });
        proxy.on('error', function (err) {
        });
    });
}, app).listen(proxyPort);
```

This is the log.

```
GET / 304 2ms
GET / 200 2ms - 6.32kb
GET http://api.ipify.org/ 200 4ms - 6.32kb
GET http://www.epochtimes.com/ 200 3ms - 6.32kb
GET http://www.minghui.org/ 200 4ms - 6.32kb
GET http://www.123cha.com/ 200 3ms - 6.32kb
GET http://www.rfa.org/english/ 404 1ms
GET http://www.ip.cn/ 200 2ms - 6.32kb
GET http://boxun.com/ 200 2ms - 6.32kb
GET http://www.wujieliulan.com/ 200 2ms - 6.32kb
```

Comment: {
  "name": "SApp",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "main": "app.js",
  "framework": "mvc",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.8",
    "ejs": "^2.5.2",
    "express": "^3.4.7",
    "express-partials": "^0.3.0",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.11",
    "nodemailer": "^0.7.1",
    "randomstring": "^1.1.5"
  }
}

Comment: If this comment is relevant to your question then edit your question with it, don't put it in a comment